# PHPUnit - Why expecting method invocation doesn't work?

Tags: phpunit, magento2

OrderHelper class is using OrderRepository class to update orders (through `save` method). I'm trying to test if `OrderRepository::save` is called inside `OrderHelper::saveOrderSource`.

But it keeps saying:

> Expectation failed for method name is equal to 'save' when invoked 1 time(s).
>   Method was expected to be called 1 times, actually called 0 times.

Please help.

**setUp() method:**

```
protected function setUp()
{
    $objectManager          = new ObjectManager($this);

    $this->orderRepository = $this->getMockBuilder(OrderRepositoryInterface::class)
        ->setMethods(['save','getList','get','delete'])
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();

    $this->helper = $objectManager->getObject(
        OrderHelper::class,
        [
            'orderRepository' => $this->orderRepository
        ]
    );
}
```

**Test class:**

```
public function testSave()
{
    $order = $this->createMock(OrderInterface::class);

    $this->orderRepository->expects($this->once())
        ->method('save')
        ->with($order)
        ->willReturn($this->helper);

    $this->helper->saveOrderSource($order, 1);
}
```

**Original method in OrderHelper::saveOrderSource:**

```
public function saveOrderSource(OrderInterface $order, $source = null) : OrderHelper
{
    if(!is_null($order) && !$source){
        $order->setOrderSource($source);
        $this->orderRepository->save($order);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add this code

```
    $this->orderRepository->expects($this->once())
        ->method('save')
        ->with($order)
        ->willReturn($this->helper);
```

In the setup before of the following line

```
$this->helper = $objectManager->getObject(
```